# Laravel blade form select statement has index for value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Having searched and tried to resolve this I can't seem to work it out.

I have a simple static method in a class that returns a list of options.  I am using this to populate a select element in a form.  This works fine but I'm using the Laravel blade shortcut language and the value of each option is coming out as the index of the array, which is sent to the database when persisting the results of the form:

```
{!! Form::select('type', \App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

HTML produced:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
<option value="0">Commercial</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Military</option>
<option value="2">Galactic</option><option value="3">Private</option>
</select>
```

Static method called:

```
class Airporttype
{
protected static $types = [
    "Commercial",
    "Military",
    "Galactic",
    "Private",
];
public static function all()
{
    return static::$types;
}
}
```

By using the 'null' option, it will give me the option = selected if the database matches what is already saved for that record.

I can achieve it buy doing the following, but wanted to use the blade shortcode style as it's clean (below is what I have tested elsewhere in te form and works):

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="form-control">
    @foreach (\App\Http\Utilities\Country::all() as $country => $code) 
        <option value="{{ $country }}" @if ($country == $airport->country) selected = 'selected' @endif>{{ $country }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>


 Array dump of Aiporttype::all();
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Commercial' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Military' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Galactic' (length=8)
  3 => string 'Private' (length=7)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
{!! Form::select('type', \App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all(), $airport->country, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have types in strings, you can try to change your array to:

```
protected static $types = [
    'commercial => 'Commercial',
    'military' => 'Military',
    'galactic' => 'Galactic',
    'private' => 'Private',
];
```

Comment: I've updated my code. If your example with `@foreach` is the working example, this should work too.

Comment: When I add that option     $airport->type is just outputs the array index as the value

Comment: The thing is you have to put the airport type instead of `null`, for example: `{!! Form::select('type', \App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all(), 2, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}` - here 'Galactic' will be `selected`. Test it. If it works, you just need to insert right variable with Id instead of 2 to make it work.

Comment: OK will give it a go but that won't work dynamically - there's no id I can pass the only value i have in the dbase is type ('military') etc.  So as you can see in the @foreach statement above I can populate the values  and then conditionally check whether (type) validates against the option value

Comment: Well, then you should create column with type_id in the database. Or you can try to change your a different array. Please look at the code in my updated post.

Comment: as you mentioned above, i tried the key as the value but this gave the same result...

Comment: UPDATE @Alexey - your strings as keys works great!  I had to have the same value for both i.e. uppercase first letter etc, so that when it goes to DB it is formatted correctly.   It seems crazy to do this though, if it was a proper associative array I would struggle...

Answer (score 0):

To get an array indexed by its values you can try something like this

```php
$types = \App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all();

$types = array_combine($types, $types);

-- view --

{!! Form::select('type', $types, null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

Comment: on this one I get Undefined variable: types.  It's in my controller and passing to view with return view::make('airports.edit', $types);

Answer (score 0):

Working Fine for me...
In controller

```
View::share('types',\App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all());
```

In View

```
{!! Form::select('types',array(''=>'- Select types -')+$types,Input::get('types',null),array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Comment: mean your variable could not share here 
did you putted your code into controller ? View::share('types',\App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all());

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_flip](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_flip.asp) function in php:

```
{!! Form::select('type', array_flip(\App\Http\Utilities\Airporttype::all()), $airport->country, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

Simple elegant function!

Comment: good one!  value is now correct label but the visual is 0, 1, 2 etc